# Alternative to UDF in aws redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am creating views on a redshift table, but would like to have some sort of argument that I can pass to limit the data I get back from the view. The table is for the whole month and joins take a lot of time. I looked into redshift documentation but it says that redshift doesnot support user-defined functions. Is there any alternative to choose besides views/UDF....

To be particular, I have a query like:

```
with lookup as
(
    Select DISTINCT * 
    from Table 
    where property_value = 'myproperty' 
        AND time_stamp > ‘2015-07-##’ 
        AND time_stamp < ‘2015-07-##’ 
    order by sortkey
)
Select * from lookup where ……..
```

I wanted to be flexible in changing the time_stamp. Also, would like user to pass arguments to the created view and grab data just for specified timestamps.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to query the DB? Could you use a scripting language to pass a paramaterised query? something like `Select DISTINCT * from Table where property_value = 'myproperty' AND time_stamp > ?`?

Comment: I am trying to have something residing in database that can be utilized by some other person as well. I looked for different options like prepared executions, UDF(Not spported in redshift) to achieve this purpose, but no luck....

Comment: Did you try the PREPARE statement option: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PREPARE.html

Comment: Prepare statement cannot be placed within a view query! :(

Answer (score 1):

A presentation at the AWS re:Invent conference in November 2014 included mention of User Defined Functions as upcoming features.

See: [AWS re:Invent SDD414 - Amazon Redshift Deep Dive and What's Next](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/sdd414-amazon-redshift-deep-dive-and-whats-next-aws-reinvent-2014) (Slide 19+)

Answer (score 0):

Update: Redshift now also supports SQL UDF's

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-sql-udf.html